# Collecting offline spatial data on iPads?

Tags: software-recommendations, mobile, offline, data-collection, ipad

I a looking for an iOS app or any approach, that will allow me to do offline map-based surveys and upload the data back to one single database once I am online (like the Esri Collector), but:

1. in Collector, once I finish one respondent, the second respondent sees the answers, I want to start with blank map.
2. I will have about 30 people with iPads in the field, I do not want them to see all the answers in one map
3. I don't have a budget to buy an app

Any ideas?

I can of course take for each respondent a new map, but then I would end up with 700 maps/shapefiles I would have to merge afterwards, what is not user friendly - so I need something like Qfield (QGIS plugin) that would work at iPads.

Comment: For software recommendations there is the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: You might find GISCloud useful, but perhaps the number of users you require might put this out of reach too: http://www.giscloud.com/

Comment: Ok, I found the "solution", although it is not superb, it works. I set up layers to be 100% transparent, it means, that users can see layer while creating it, but then it becomes invisible and another user on same iPad wont see previous answers. Works well for me right now.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking into [Survey123 for ArcGIS](https://survey123.arcgis.com/) is an alternative.

Esri describes it as:

> Survey123 for ArcGIS is a simple and intuitive form-centric data gathering solution that makes creating, sharing, and analyzing surveys possible in just three easy steps:
>
> Ask Questions
>   Quickly design powerful surveys and publish them into ArcGIS.
>
> Get the Answers
>   Enable your workforce with the Survey123 for ArcGIS mobile app to capture answers in the field.
>
> Make the Best Decisions
>   Analyze answers from the field in real-time to support decision making.

Comment: What are the back-end software requirements that might put the budget of this system out of reach?

Comment: Survey123 does not allow to draw spatial features, it only allows you to answer questions and record your position as point (as far as I know)...